# replacing an infinitive phrase that modifies a noun

Tags: infinitives

Here are some sentences where infinitives modify a noun. depending on the feature of a noun, whether it's a person or class or something, the way I should interpret the role of the infinitive is different. So I've made my own interpretation of this by writing sentences that mean the same that the original one does. Am I right to do this? The reason I do this is all for the sake of me fully understanding how to use "infinitive".

> 1. If you need **anyone to talk with about this matter**, feel free to call me anytime.
>
>    =If you need anyone that you can talk with about this matter, feel free to call me anytime.
> 2. I'm currently participating in **a class to practice English by speaking only in it.**
>
>    =I'm currently participating in a class in which to practice English by speaking only in it.
>
>    =I'm currently participating in a class that is intended or designed for people to practice English by speaking only in it.
> 3. When you think you're ready, gather up some **people to listen to your speech**
>
>    =When you think you're ready, gather up some people who is willing to listen to your speech
>
>    =When you think you're ready, gather up some people who has an willingness to listen to your speech
> 4. w and b are **parameters to be solved.**
>
>    = w and b are parameters that is to be solved.
>
>    = w and b are parameters that has to to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, your thinking is correct in these transformations. The revised examples carry the same meaning as the originals with infinitive.  However, there are some unrelated problems:

In #2, you need to repeat the word "English", or "class",  to avoid awkwardness/ambiguity, because as you have put the sentence,
- . . . class..,to practice English by speaking only in it

"it" can refer back to "class" or to
"English".  So, try this:

- . . . class to practice English by speaking only in English.

Or this:

- . . . class to practice English by speaking only English in class.

As for #3 and #4, you have missed the *agreement in number*:

- ...people who **are** willing... , ..,people who **have  a** willingness
- parameters that **are** to be solved..., parameters that **have** to be solved